# Check for a Sheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I might have Sheets in my excel workbook named as Data1, Data2,...
What i want to know is how many such Sheets are there in my Workbook.

I was trying to compare the sheet name and keep a count. But it did not work Properly.

So hoping that someone might help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
msgbox thisworkbook.sheets.count
```

that will return the number of sheet sijn the workbook.

To return the number of sheets with names like 'Data' do this:

```
Dim iCountSheets As Integer
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
'
For Each oSheet In Sheets
    If oSheet.Name Like "Data*" Then
       iCountSheets = iCountSheets + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox iCountSheets & " sheets like data"
```

another way is to iterate through the sheets collection by index:

```
Dim iCountSheets As Integer, iIdx As Integer
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
'
For iIdx = 1 To Sheets.Count ' non-zero based collection
    If Sheets(iIdx).Name Like "Data*" Then
       iCountSheets = iCountSheets + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox iCountSheets & " sheets like data"
```

Comment: My typing wasn't quick enough either!

Comment: I see that you have updated your post after i upvoted it but the latest edit has 2 major errors. `1.` Your If is missing an End-If `2` Setting `iIdx = 0` will give you an error. I am surprised at the upvotes this post is getting after your edit LOL.

Comment: +1 (*2) yes, you are right, I copy pasted and typed too fast and forgot that the sheet collection is not zero based!

Comment: c'mon, capitalization of keywords and variable names is done by the vb editor after the OP copy pastes it into a code module...so those are more *presentation failings* rather than **code errors** :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works really well for me. Exactly what i was looking for.

I didn't know u had a "like" in VBA.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying?

```
'~~> Case Sensitive
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shCount As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "Data*" Then shCount = shCount + 1
    Next ws

    Debug.Print shCount
End Sub

'~~> Or use the below if you have sheets like data1, Data2, DaTa3 etc
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shCount As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) Like "DATA*" Then shCount = shCount + 1
    Next ws

    Debug.Print shCount
End Sub
```